# Finding the common item between two list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey guys I need help on this past test question. Basically I am given two list of objects, and I am suppose to find the number of items that appear in the same position of the first list and the second. I have an example that was provided.

```
>>> commons(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'x', 'b', 'd'])
2
>>> commons(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'x', 'b', 'd'])
2
```

I am having trouble writing out the code. Our class is using python 3. I have no idea where to start writing this from. It is a first year programming course and I never did programming in my life.

Comment: What pointers did your instructor give you? If none at all - you should be asking them for more information. If some, what was it, what hints were given, how are you expected to approach this etc...? You may well get some very clever answers/one-liners but they may not be of any use to you, and would be unlikely to help you learn.

Comment: If you are indeed a math geek, I would recommend looking up unions and intersections in Python using [Sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Comment: sets is not what you want. You are checking whether the values are the same or not at each *position* in the lists, right? Loop over all position and test the lists at each position until you reach the end of the shorter of the two lists. Done.

Comment: Is this any help? `commons = lambda L1, L2: sum(map(lambda x,y: 1 if x == y else 0, L1, L2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a simple problem for a beginner. A more straightforward approach would use functions like `sum` and `zip` with a list comprehension like so:

```
def commons(L1, L2):
    return  sum(el1 == el2 * 1 for el1, el2 in zip(L1, L2))
```

A more typical but error prone approach taken by beginners is:

```
def commons(L1, L2):
    count = 0
    for i, elem in enumerate(L2):
        if elem == L1[i]:
            count += 1
    return count
```

I say this is more error prone because there are more parts to get right.

Without using `enumerate` you could do:

```
def commons(L1, L2):
    count = 0
    for i, range(len(L2)):
        if L1[i] == L2[i]:
            count += 1
    return count
```

but these previous two will work only if `len(L2) <= len(L1)`.  See what I mean by more error prone? To fix this you would need to do:

```
def commons(L1, L2):
    count = 0
    for i, range(min(len(L2), len(L1))):
        if L1[i] == L2[i]:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: I tried giving your third code a try but I got this one error from our marker saying Test description:
Test case for the second list being a shorter than the first.

Message:
IndexError
list index out of range

Comment: is it because you did range(len(l1) and we should do the same for l2 ?

Comment: Yes, Since len(L2) < len(L1) it would give an error.  I updated it. The first method would not have that problem nor will the others if you make sure len(L2) <= len(L1) as in your example.

Answer (score 3):

I think a more straightforward solution would be:

```
def commons(L1,L2):
    return len([x for x in zip(L1,L2) if x[0]==x[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this would work:

```
def commons(l1, l2):
   return sum(1 for v1,v2 in map(None, l1,l2) if v1 == v2)
```

- Note: The degenerate form of map used here results in None being returned for all values in the shorter list (so even if l1 and l2 are not the same length, it'll work.)  It assumes that both lists all have values (i.e., L1 and L2 do not contain None - since that would end up in false positives if one list was shorter than the other.)